# Why is "use pen as pointer" not working in OneNote?

Tags: office365, microsoft-onenote, pen

I have Microsoft 365 and I use a Wacom tablet with a stylus to take notes on my computer. The cursor when using the pen on OneNote is very small and I cannot locate it so I use the "pen as pointer" feature so that I can actually see the mouse.

However, just today, this feature stopped working. The button still appears but it's greyed out so when I click on "pen as pointer", nothing happens. I have tried repairing the app and reinstalling it but nothing is working.

How I can fix this or if you have another solution to my problem of not being able to see my cursor when using pen mode in OneNote?

Comment: Which OS are you on?  If you're on Windows, you could try enabling the "Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key" checkbox under Mouse Properties.  Then, just tap CTRL key anytime to quickly locate your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, found the solution here regarding reverting back and it worked for me:

https://www.reddit.com/r/OneNote/comments/uucx26/use_pen_as_pointer_in_onenote_desktop_not_working/

I reverted back to an older version until it worked for me.  I just chose version 11425.20244 cause it was old enough that I was sure it would work.